# Query on boolean field on ElasticSearch repository

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using `ElasticsearchRepository` and want to query on boolean property.

Sample snippet here:

```
class TempBean
{
       private boolean isActive;
}


interface MyEntityRepository implements CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> 
{
   TempBean findByIsActiveTrue();
}
```

How to query on the active property without passing it as param to the abstract method?
This is possible if I would have JpaRepository as per this answer [how-to-query-for-boolean-property-with-spring-crudrepository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601204)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as can be seen in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.criterions). Just remove "Is" from your function:

```
interface MyEntityRepository implements CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> 
{
   TempBean findByActiveTrue();
}
```

As a side note, I don't know about your schema but I would suggest you use `Page<TempBean>` as your return type, which would require `PageRequest` as an argument. This is in case more than one `TempBean` docs have `"active":"true"` and your function is likely to return more than one records.

Comment: sorry, I've updated the question. I got your answer.

Comment: My bad. I was probably hasty with my assessment of the question. But I'm still not sure what you want. You don't want to pass `isActive` as a parameter?